# Django wizard interaction between forms

Tags: django, wizard, django-formwizard

I need to make a two form wizard. In one form I need to gather some data, process that and prepopulate a field in the second form. What's the best/easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `get_form_initial()` method in your wizard class, for the 2nd step, use data from first step using `get_cleaned_data_for_step()`.

Something like:

```
class myWizardView:

    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        if int(step) == 1:
            # get cleaned data from prev step
            return self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(str(int(step) - 1))
```

You may want to manipulate the dict to have appropriate attribute names etc.

More reference at [Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)

Comment: Well... that doesn't work :( The first thing is that the steps are numbered from 0, and the second is that they are strings. So in fact I need to check if `step == '1'`. That's not a big deal. The biggest problem I have is that `self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(i)` where i in [0,1,2] returns None. And `self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')` ends with `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Comment: I've added some info to the previous comment, I sent not finished one by mistake.

Comment: @SzymonGuz, django stores steps as string, so pass `i` as string using `str(i)` to `get_cleaned_data_for_step()`. I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: Well. It looks like the `get_form_initial` function is called for all previous steps. So when I'm in step 1, and by mistake I called `get_cleaned_data_for_step(step-1)` outside `if step==1`, then it was also called for the `step=0`, so it wanted to get data for `step == -1` which didn't exist, what ended with the RuntimeError. Thank you very much, now it works.